Double point scheme and vanishing of function
In Example II-9 of Eisenbud's The Geometry of Schemes, he considers the scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec}K[x]/(x^2)$ and makes the following claim:
$\bullet$ A function $f\in K[x]$ on $\mathbb{A}^1_K$ vanishes on $X$ if and only if both $f$ and its derivative vanish at $0$.
I approached the "if" part: if $f=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ vanishes at $0$ (i.e. the ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(x)$), then $f(x)=f'(x)=0$, implying that $a_0=a_1=0$. Hence $\bar{f}=0$ and $f(\mathfrak{p})=\bar{f}(\mathfrak{p})=0$ where $\bar{f}$ is the image of $f$ under the quotient map $K[x]\to K[x]/(x^2)$.
However, the only if part is confusing me. A function vanishing on $X$ means the evaluation at the point $[(x)]\in X$ is zero, which does not guarantee that the derivative is 0 as well (e.g the function $f=x$). I am not sure which part went wrong. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

I think your definition of vanishing along $X$ is incorrect, or at least not the right one to use here. You want to look at the functions on $\mathbb{A}^1_K$ which restrict to $0$ when you restrict them to $X$ itself.

I was wondering if $\bar{f}=0$ was what the author meant here. However, I did not find the clarification of such notation in the book. Value of functions is defined on page 22 via the localization and taking the field of fractions. And these two notions do not coincide, at least in the case when $R$ is non-reduced.

You have a morphism of schemes, so on the structural sheaves you have a morphism which is $K[X] \rightarrow K[X]/(x^2)$. $f$ vanishing on $X$ not only means a vanishing on the reduced point associated, but a vanishing on the global sections of the sheaf $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$. As I said earlier, it is just a vanishing modulo $(x^2)$. With this definition your answer should be clear.

It is certainly the case that $\overline{f} = 0$ is what is meant here. The way I think about it is that if $Z = V(I) \subset \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a closed subscheme defined by $I$, then a function $f \in A$ vanishing along $Z$ is the same as $f \in I$. This also recovers the notion of 'vanishing at a point' which you describe, by looking at a maximal ideal.

$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
Let $X$ be any scheme, and $Z\subset X$ a closed subscheme. Then there is an induced map of rings $\O_X(X)\rightarrow \O_Z(Z)$ given by the sheaf morphism coming from the closed embedding $Z\hookrightarrow X$. A function, $f\in \O_X(X)$ vanishes on $Z$ if it is in the kernel of this ring homomorphism.
Now if  these are affine schemes then $X=\Spec A$  and $Z$ is of the form $\Spec A/I$ for some ideal $I$, and the closed embedding comes from the ring homomorphism $\pi:A\rightarrow A/I$. If $f$ is a global function on $\Spec A$, then $f$ vanishes if and only if it lies in $I$. In your example, this corresponds exactly to the statement that $f\in \langle x^2\rangle$, so the degree $0$ and degree $1$ part of $f$ must be zero. In other words, both $f$ and its first derivative vanish at zero.

Thanks for making this clear. I wonder is it legal to generalize this notion of vanishing? Let $i:Z\to X$ be any subscheme (not necessarily closed), can we say that $f\in\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ vanishes on $Z$ if it is in the kernel of the ring hom $\mathcal{O}X(X)\to i*\mathcal{O}_Z(X)$?

In general, sets obtained by some form of “vanishing condition” are closed, as this is usually a closed condition (this is not precise but that’s how I think about it). You can absolutely take a sheaf of ideals on $X$ and obtain a closed sub scheme via the vanishing locus of functions/sections on $X$, but this will be closed.
